# submit check all validation function

Tags: jquery

[please check this link first](https://jsfiddle.net/Tedeee/unvwhjn1/17/)

my intention is check all validation once i clicked submit but problem start here.

method 1
it work on checking all validation empty or not ,but problem is it go it one by one , so after you click submit only 1st border be red.
(my intention is check all those didt fill right be red border)

method 2
once you click submit , all those didt fill will be red border just i like i want but if one of the function fill in successful and you press submit the form will pass.

i want the get all those empty be red border after i click submit and yet they need to fill all field in order to pass the form.

(but i dont wanted to extra function inside)
exp(i dont wanted to do this)

```
function submitFormFunction(event){
        event.preventDefault();
            checkname();
            checkpass();
            checkmail();
            if(!checkname() && !checkpass() && !checkemail()){
            return false;
            }else{    
            return true;
            }
    }
```

is like adding those function for extra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the [short circuting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation) nature of [logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

```
function submitFormFunction(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var valid = checkname();
    valid = checkpass() && valid;
    valid = checkemail() && valid;
    return valid;
}
```

Note: Not sure why are you calling `preventDefault` then returning `true/false`

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/goh3dkdq/)

Comment: one more question do i have to do those function one by one ? cause i have few more function.

Comment: i really appreciate my friends , thank for helping !~ is all i wanted.